# What is the purpose of -a "$EXTENSION" in the procmail / postfix integration?

Tags: postfix, procmail

The suggested integration method for procmail into postfix [recommends](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html) the following:

> mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"

All it says about `$EXTENSION` is

> EXTENSION
>
> The optional address extension.

What is passing this to `procmail` doing?

Answer (score 3):

`$EXTENSION` ends up being the latter half of a email address that contains an extension that is (mostly) ignored by the mailer:

> ${extension}
>
> This  macro  expands to the extension part of a recipient address.  For example, with  an  address  user+foo@domain the extension is foo.

When passed to `procmail` using the `-a` parameter, the assigns the variable `$1` to the extension (`"foo"` in the example above) within `procmail`.

This allows simpler filtering rules within `procmail` based on the recipient's email address if the recipient is using address extensions.

Answer (score 3):

If your mailbox is `you@example.net`, Postfix will deliver `you+stackexchange@example.net`, `you+4chan@example.net`, etc to this mailbox with the part after the `+` as the extension.

As far as the MTA is concerned, the extension is simply ignored. You can basically invent new unique mail addresses on the fly by creating new extension parts on a whim whenever you need to share your email address.

In Postfix, [the extension separator is configurable.](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_delimiter) Out of the box, it is unset, though Debian ships a canned Postfix configuration where it is set to a plus character, which is also the character used e.g. by Sendmail; Qmail uses a dash.

Eli the Bearded used to publish an email addressing FAQ about this; it's long abandoned, and obsolescent in some parts, but you can still find it [archived on faqs.org.](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/mail/addressing/)